# If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2(\lambda-3)^4$, then the rank(A)=4.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about the "True or False":

If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2(\lambda-3)^4$, then the rank(A)=4.

I do not understand that why this is not true? Is it the reason of
$$rank(A)+nullity(A)=6$$

Comment: $\text{null}(A)$ may have dimension $1$. If that is the case then $\text{rank}(A)=5$.

Comment: @mathmath How get $n(A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False.  Look at any matrix whose JNF is  $\begin {pmatrix}3&0&0&0&0&0\\0&3&0&0&0&0\\0&0&3&0&0&0\\0&0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end {pmatrix} $.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the nullity of $A$ is the **geometric** multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$. On the other hand, we are only given that the **algebraic** multiplicity of $0$ is $2$.

Comment: I do understand why the nullity of $A$ is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0? Is the definition of nullity of $A$ is the dimension of null space?

Comment: Yes, the definition of the nullity of $A$ is the dimension of the nullspace.

Comment: But why the dimension of the nullspace is same as the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$?

Comment: @Hermi The geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace. In general, the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$ is the null space of $A - \lambda I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix).